# Lighthouse and bubblewrap PWA check fails when testing offline for start_url

Tags: progressive-web-apps, offline, lighthouse, bubblewrap

I have a PWA that I am trying to use to create an Android app (apk) with a trusted web activity using **bubblewrap** tool (https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap). To check the PWA criteria, it uses Lighthouse which fails the following audit step (red):

```
start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline
Timed out waiting for start_url to respond.
```

But actually the step regarding to current page being offline is ok (green):

```
Current page responds with a 200 when offline
```

My PWA is hosted at an url: https://example.com/myapp/. So the service worker (manifest) has the startup url and Scope at "/myapp/". So if I access this page in Offline mode (Check the box "Offline" in the dev tools "Application" tab) it serves an offline page that is cached at the beginning when the service worker is installed (I followed this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match and everything seems to work fine, I tested even on my mobile in airplane mode).

Also, the startup page redirects to ?locale=en but it is the same webpage (so in Offline mode every url seems to show my offline html page). What is even stranger is that in about 20-30 audit reports, one time this step passed, randomly)

I am doing the Lighthouse tests on Mac, Chrome 84.

**EDIT:**
So I made some tests and I saw that if I access http://example.com/myapp (instead of http://example.com/myapp/ - there is a / at the end), the offline html page is not shown anymore. But in the manifest the scope and start_url are set to "/myapp/" exactly so I don't know if this is an issue (if I set them to "/myapp" the PWA won't work anymore saying that there is no service worker at that path, which sounds strange because my jetty server redirects /myapp to /myapp/ which both should be the same resource)

Answer (score 0):

The Bubblewrap lighthouse check is a wrapper around the [Pagespeed Insights API]. The PSI API can be a bit flaky and fail to run at times. If the failure is constant, I'd recommend running the URL against [PSI](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), as you should get the same report, but with more detailed information.